# write r file to csv -- "object not found"

Tags: r, export-to-csv

Hello I need to make my R file into a CSV file. I have searched stackoverflow for different methods to accomplish this, but nothing is working. Each time, it says:

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'refine_clean' not found
```

My file is definitely named refine_clean.R. I have linked a screenshot here:
[R Studio CSV Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isVYN.png)

Comment: The dataframe you want to write does not exist! Most likely, something upstream of `write.table()` and `write.csv()` failed. Scan the entire script's output carefully and look for error messages.

Comment: Thank you. There was a problem reading the original csv file but it eventually worked. That was the only error. https://imgur.com/a/rg1ZP9z

Comment: `refine_clean.R` is the name of your R scrip file, not the name of the file you want to export/write. It looks like you actually want to write (I mean save) `d5`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is named refine_clean but you have no data.frame or object named refine_clean, which is what `write_table` and `write.csv` are looking for.

based on the screen shot, it is not clear what you want to produce. If it is the last object you created (`d5`), you may want something like this

```
write.csv(d5, "refine_clean.csv")
```

Comment: ah i see what you mean. Yes, it is the last object, d5. I used your code -- thanks! -- it no longer causes an error but I also don't see a csv file created anywhere... is there another step? https://imgur.com/s2aKZZZ

Comment: I also tried with this refine_clean <- write.table(d5)
write.csv(refine_clean, file = "refine_clean.csv")

Comment: The file is saved in your working directory by default. If you want to save it in a particular folder use `write.csv(d5, "C:/Users/blablaPathToFolder/refine_clean.csv")`

Comment: What @ANG said. Additionally, you can just scan your local machine for the file, such as typing "refine_clean.csv" in your File Explorer on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

you cant convert all your file as an csv, you need to select the object, like d5
write.csv(d5,file = "name_of_the_file")

Comment: Please, could you explain how your answer is different from Peter_Evan's one?